# Minimum value for each element in array

Tags: python, pyomo

I have a basic question as I am new to both Python and Pyomo. I have set a constraint that works properly to set the sum of the elements in array equal to 1.

```
def Allocation(model):
    return sum(model.alloc[i] for i in model.alloc) == 1
model.allocationSum  = Constraint(rule=Allocation)
```

What must I do to then have each element of the array be greater than or equal to 0.01? The following did not work:

```
def allocationMinimum(model):
    for i in model.alloc
        return model.alloc[i] >= 0.01
model.minimumWeight = Constraint(rule=allocationMinimum)
```

Thanks.

Comment: For greater than use `>`, for greater than or equal `>=`. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays. There's a difference in python

Comment: @JelleWestra Sorry, I meant to say greater than or equal to originally. Still gives an invalid syntax error

Comment: That's because you're missing a colon after the loop

Comment: Also, when you get an error, post it with full traceback please. Use the [edit] button to update your question

Answer (score 2):

This is called a lower bound. You can specify them in the variable declaration. See: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Good points above on code structure, but I'm not sure if the central question was covered.  Erwin is correct that this can be done by setting bounds on the variables when they are created.  The general form for doing a constraint "for each" value of the index with a function-rule combo is below.

```
def allocation_minimum(model, i):
    return model.alloc[i] >= 0.01
model.min_weight = Constraint(model.i, rule=allocation_minimum)
```

In this construct, the first variable (or variables) of the Constraint constructor are the indexing variable(s) and the "rule" will be called with **each value** of the index set(s), creating 1 constraint expression for each value of the index (`model.i` in this case).  In this case where it is a simple min, this is equivalent to setting a lower bound on the variable.

Answer (score -1):

By having a [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) within the loop, you ensure that the function exits on the first iteration, so you will get the rule applied to the first element. One way to do this is with the builtin [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
def allocation_minimum(model):
    return all(i >= 0.01 for i in model.alloc)
```

Another way is to use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) on the inverse condition:

```
def allocation_minimum(model):
    return not any(i < 0.01 for i in model.alloc)
```

If you must use an explicit [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) loop, you need to wait til the end of the loop, when you've checked all the elements, before returning `True`:

```
def allocation_minimum(model):
    for i in model.allocation:
        if i < 0.01:
            return False
    return True
```

On a related note, it's [conventional](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#intermezzo-coding-style) to name objects, including functions, using `snake_case`, except classes, which use `CamelCase`. I've renamed `allocation_minimum` to conform to this convention.

All loops and [conditionals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) need a colon at the end of the line. That was the cause of your original syntax error.